# Run Python Script in Javascript using Flask in a website on server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Currently, I am using ajax to run a python script in javascript. Basically, I have created a website that accepts and converts a pdf file into CSV by running the python script and it is put on the server. So I expect that when I upload a pdf file, it will automatically run the ajax code. The python script is a flask script. But it will only alert the response, which is the python script, without actually running it. Could someone know why? Thanks.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(".image-upload-wrap").hide();

      $(".file-upload-image").attr("src", e.target.result);
      $(".file-upload-content").show();

      $(".image-title").html(input.files[0].name);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./BPRecordsParser.py ",
        // dataType: 'py',
        data: {
          param: input.files[0].name + " " + e.target.result
        },
        success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
          alert('err');
        }
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);



  } else {
    removeUpload();
  }
}
```

Comment: If it shows a response it certainly ran it. Why do you say it didn't? What do you expect to happen? Also, if the problem is with your python script, you should really show a relevant section of it.

Comment: Oh, wait, you mean that you get the source code of your python script as a response? If that's the case, you can't call a script like that without having a server capable of running python scripts given their url (which is not how it's usually done anyway)

Comment: It is hard to say what is going there. I believe you should check logs on your server (i.e. by putting there some logger string before and after the execution to track what had happened).